# Que significa '&quot' en el codigo?

Tags: javascript

Mi codigo estaba así

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">
    Turn off the light
</button>
```

y la siguiente vez que revise me encontré con esto:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;MyImage&quot;).src=&quot;pic_bulboff_off.gif&quot;">
    Apagado
</button>
```

Por que sucede esto en el código, debido a que? existe alguna consecuencia o es perjudicial de alguna manera? Me gustaría estar al tanto de todo, gracias.

Comment: eso significa las comillas, muy probablemente tengas algo que te genere ese código por ejemplo php o algún otro lenguaje de servidor

Comment: Hola  Jose Luis Esparza, algun ejemplo de como mi codigo termino con esos quotes? Quizas fue manipulado o paso a traves de X programa? Gracias.

Comment: esa pagina solo esta echa con html osea no es un template ni usas algún otro lenguaje o framework en ese proyecto ?

Answer (score 5):

El `&quot` significa una Comilla simple `'` la cual esta siendo codificada segun las reglas de `HTML` quizas por algún lenguaje que estes usando o la codificación del archivo.

Puedes encontrar mas información en el siguiente enlace [Link de Explicación mas completa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916943/uses-for-the-quot-entity-in-html)

Comment: No entiendo cómo el comentario que indica q es una comilla simple tiene la mayor cantidad de vistas, cuando es una comilla Doble no sencilla.

Answer (score 1):

`&quot;` indica comilla doble (**"**).

Consulte esta [fuente](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_13.html) para obtener mas información.

Comment: Hola Maurcio, alguna  ideade como mi codigo termino con esos quotes? Quizas fue manipulado o paso a traves de X programa? Gracias

Comment: @Hoozuki creo que es por el uso combinado de comillas dobles y sencillas. Aunque no creo que le ocasione problemas, le recomiendo crear una función que ejecute esta línea: `document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'`

Answer (score 0):

Son comillas sencillas.

```
('myImage')
(&quot;MyImage&quot;)
```

Esta lista te puede servir de referencia.

https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score -4):

Hace referencia :a la cuota de impuestos y precio que ,cada país. carga a productos internacionales ;es por eso ,que cada país en un mismo juego tiene precios distintos..
"&quote,(Eu, 10:1, Es, Ru, ref,etc..)" normalmente corre en una extensión similar a: .umb
de unix